# Display data from query in textbox

Tags: c#

This is my entire code i want to select max(pid) and want to display that into textbox

```
public PatientRegistration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connectionstring = "DATABASE=hmanagmentsystem;UID=root;PASSWORD=;SERVER=localhost";
        con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
        con.Open();
    }

  private void PatientRegistration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select max(pid) from patientreg",con);
        txtpatientid.Text = command.ToString();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Where are you executing the `command` ?

Comment: You need to execute the command, then put the result into the textbox

Answer (score 2):

```
txtpatientid.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: suppose i have max(pid)=1001 if i want to display values of 1002 which is through +1 into max value so how can i do

Comment: You can handle in your query, or in code. `SELECT max(pid) + 1 As NextPid from patientreg` --or-- `((int)command.ExecuteScalar() + 1).ToString()`.

Looks like you're new to the site. If my answer above worked for you, please accept as the answer to your question. Also, I'm happy to help on closely related questions in this thread, but you should post new questions in a new thread to give others a chance to answer.